# Excel VBA - Is it possible to use two last row in range select?

Tags: excel, vba

This involves two last rows so please bear with me, last rows will be different every time.

I have a large dataset and need to copy formulas from the last row of columns L through AC down to the last row of whatever that happens to be in column A (which Column A last row will always be greater than L). Think of it Columns on the left (A-K) update and columns on right dont update and are left behind so i need to bring columns on right down (these are formulas in these columns).

Columns A-K last row is 18500
Columns L-AC last row is 18450

So i need to "fill" or copy row L18450:Ac18450 down to L18500:AC18500

Currently I have

`dim LLastrow as long`

`dime ALastrow as long`

`LLastrow = Range ("L" & rows.count).end(xlup).row`

`ALastrow = Range ("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row`

`Range("L" & LLastrow : "AC" & LLastrow).Select`
but this give me an **ERROR**

The next step would look like

`Selection.copy`

`Range("L" & ALastrow).pastespecial`

Comment: `Range("L" & LLastrow & ":" & "AC" & LLastrow).Select`

Comment: You don't need to select the cell at all FYI.

Comment: This Got rid of my error!! I made a mistake on my paste code but fixed that and did what i wanted it to. Thanks so much for the quick reponse!!